# configure linux launcher to passed variables

Tags: linux, terminal

I have found that i can use something called a launcher in linux by right clicking the desktop.

i have set this to run my program in the terminal which i am happy about but i want to give it some default values when it runs.

Im guessing i should put the values after the program path with - befor them but im not sure about what im doing.

can some point me to a document or something that lists the ways to include values and what i can include in the path.

also if i do this how will my program read them ? will they be passed to main ?

Is it possible to set it up in a way that the program does not know how many variables are coming at start up but will read as many as it gets.

im using c++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I recall correctly running a terminal is something like

```
rxvt -backspacekey  -sl 2500 -tn msys -geometry 80x25 -e 'script.sh -param' --login -i
```

-e command arg ...                command to execute

So create a file named myApp.sh (pretty much an equivalent of a .bat on windows)

enter the following:

```
!/bin/sh
rxvt -geometry 80x25 -e 'yourExecutableName yourCommandLine' --login -i
```

After saving, just chmod +x on the file (so Linux will consider it as an executable)

```
chmod +x myApp.sh
```

After this, you can run it from anywhere on your machine (if the dir is in the PATH enviroment variable) or via double click in Gnome File Manager.

If you need to pass args also to the shell, you can access every single param with 
$0, $1, $2 (equivalents to %1, %2 in MS batch).

For command lines, a C/C++ program starts usually with a function main

```
int main (int argc, char ** argv) {
  exit(0);
}
```

argc is the number of arguments received in input, while argv is a pointer to an array of char * (the actual commandline), you may parse 'em directly.

PS: note that I use rxvt, you probably want to change this to xterm o gterm or whatever terminal you prefer to use.

Comment: sorry but i dont have a clue what your saying. where do i put this code ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need C++ for this.  Basically, you do it pretty much as you
would do it under Windows, but the exact details depend on the window
manager you are using (Gnome, KDE, etc.).  The program information is
passed to main via `argv` (which is also the preferred way of getting it
in Windows, I believe).  You do not have access to the raw command line.

Comment: no i want a file that i can double click this would be the script. that script would open a terminal and run my program that is in c++ and pass it certain letters. how can i tell what windows manager im using ?

Comment: The usual scripting language on Linux is `bash`, but you can use pretty much anything.  You may not need it; you can specify an arbitrary command line when configuring the button.  The window manager should be visually recognizable; if nothing else, there's an about button somewhere which will tell you which version, etc.  And the arguments which are passed to your program show up in `argv`.

Comment: what button ? im looking at the desktop of a centos machine and i want to put a file there that when clicked will open the terminal in the same way the button in the bar at the top works but have it pass in variables. i am really confused by what you are talking about.

Comment: Icon, button or whatever.  You asked about reacting when you clicked on something on the desktop.  This is done by creating an icon on the desktop, and configuring it to invoke your program.  With regards to the arguments, you have several alternatives: create several icons with different arguments, obtain the arguments from the clipboard (selected text), or pop up a dialog to enter them (using some sort of scripting language which supports dialogs).  The arguments will be passed to your application in `argv`.